# Is there any key binding for press CTRL and Mouse click together?

Tags: eclipse-rcp

I have editor.Now I want to enable key binding while press CTRL and Mouse click. Is there any key binding Sequence available in Eclipse RCP.

Comment: Mouse clicks don't generate key events so they can't use a key binding.

Comment: @greg-449  Example, MS world If you want to copy multiple time (multiple alphabets) then simply we are just pressing CTRL and click on character using Mouse left .I want that functionality on my tool. Is there any way using key binding or else.

Answer (score 0):

Mouse clicks don't generate key events so you can use key bindings for this.

If you have a SWT mouse event listener you can test the state of the 'modifier' keys in the listener by checking the `stateMask` in the `MouseEvent`.

For example:

```java
@Override
public void mouseDown(MouseEvent event) {

   boolean isMod1 = (event.stateMask & SWT.MOD1) != 0;

   ...
}
```

`SWT.MOD1` is Ctrl on most platforms ('Command' on macOS).